# Android canvas drawLine not full width

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I need to draw a line in a fragment. I have no problem to do that but I don't know why the line has a left and right margin (top and bottom is fine).

Here's my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = container.getContext();
        utili = new Utilities(context);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statsdepth_layout, container, false);
        gfxView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gfxview);
        int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        Log.i("LOGTAG", "W: " + width + " H: " + height);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 51));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        int startx = 0;
        int starty = 90;
        int endx = width;
        int endy = 90;
        canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
        gfxView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gfxview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**** UPDATE ***

Changing layout as below, it fixed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gfxview"
    android:scaleType="matrix"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the result (I expect the line is full width large)

[image]

Comment: Can you show your root layout? Not the fragment, the activity.

Comment: The root layout is an activity with a viewpager as layout (match_parent width and height). It is  very long to attach. In the fragment I log the width and height and the values match with the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Get your width this way and try

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
 width = display.getWidth();
```

Comment: No luck and I don't think is a width problem because my startX is 0 so I expect the horizontal line start at the beginning of screen. (and getWidth() is deprecated)

Comment: And are you sure that there is no padding given to any of those parent layouts of the view pager?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure even because the first page of the viewpager is a listview and the width is fine.

Comment: I set the ImageView scaleType to matrix and it fixed. It was unset.